# android - How to make a phone call from webview

Tags: android, webview

In my app, i am opening the url using webview. This url opens the some page that contains some phone numbers.Now i want to make a phone call without open the phone dialer if u click on the phone number. is it possible? please can anybody help me.

thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("tel:")) { 
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                        Uri.parse(url)); 
                startActivity(intent); 
        }else if(url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: where do i put it?

Answer (score 10):

Thanks JackTurky!  Here's slightly more, to show how it fits with webView:

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("tel:")) { 
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)); 
                    startActivity(intent); 
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }           
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        Log.i("TEST","URL 4: "+url);

        if (url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }else if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);

            // Send phone number to intent as data
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));

            // Start the dialer app activity with number
            startActivity(intent);
        }

            return true;

    }
```