# error: cannot find symbol variable Uri ANDROID

Tags: android

hello i am new to android and i am having a webiste which i have converted into mobile APP just by using the `**web view**` and what i want now is a function to put into the android so that i can find all the phine numbers in the website and make it clickable and dial that number on call .

function to call.
i have already aded

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

and i have tried this in mainactivity.java

```
public static void linkifyTextViews(@NonNull TextView... textViews) {
    for (TextView textView : textViews) {
        Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
}
```

**EDITED**

i have this is my mainactivity.java file

```
package com.business.i13bubbles;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView MywebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.view2);
    WebSettings webSettings = MywebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    MywebView.loadUrl("http://www.13bubbles.com");
    MywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (MywebView.canGoBack()) {
        MywebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view2, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                url.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
        view2.loadUrl(url);
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

and i am getting this error

> error: cannot find symbol method parse(String)

the id of my webview is view2

can you help me

**EDIT 2**

i think the error is here in this function

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view2, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);

        // Send phone number to intent as data
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url)); // ERROR LINE IS HERE FOR SURE 

        // Start the dialer app activity with number
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
        view2.loadUrl(url);
    }
    return true;
}
```

error: cannot find symbol variable Uri

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408378/android-how-to-make-a-phone-call-from-webview - like this?

Comment: it gives me error

Comment: The Id of the webview doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't implement `WebViewClient` correctly in your example. What I mean is that `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is not used, you need to implement that method inside `WebViewClient` for example:

```
 MywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("tel:")) { 
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)); 
                startActivity(intent); 
                return true;
        }
        MywebView.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }           
});
```

Comment: i am getting more errors now like -- error: class, interface, or enum expected

Comment: can you tell me exactly how to use this function inside the mainactivity

Comment: now it does not gives me any error but it does not work every time i click on tel link it shows me link not availabe

Comment: Does your telephone prefix starts with `tel:`?

Comment: <a href="tel:+919910673876" > yes

Answer (score 0):

As discussed earlier in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55207347/9819031), you had placed the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method wrongly. That was corrected.

In this question, you have this piece of code:

```
url.parse(url); //see the first code sample in your question
```

In this url is a string and cannot have a function `parse()`.

Maybe this is causing the error. Let me know if there is another problem.

And a suggestion for you, you've named the `WebView` in the `shouldoverrideUrlLoading()` method as `view2`. If you change it to even just `view`, it won't create any problem.