# Making a call from WebView with Intent is not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent, webview, call

I try to open the dialer while clicking on call button in post, but it is not working. All code is running but only this part not working.
I don't want to change the file uploading code, I only need to change call button code  in webview:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


WebView webView;

private static final String TEL_PREFIX = "tel:";

public String url ="https://www.negotiatar.com";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setInitialScale(0);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());



  private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        if(url.startsWith(TEL_PREFIX)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9408637/8133524 hope helpful for you.

Comment: not worked already done

Answer (score 0):

you have a big mistake in your code it seems you have nested class inside the method, are you able to do this like you have made?